# Not able to display the JSON success output in the view or alert

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, codeigniter-3

I am using CodeIgniter, I have a three input field called as name, emp_id,crm_id. I am entering the id value and sending to the controller to get all the information related to that id using AJAX an JSON. Now the issue is, I am getting the correct output in the network tab but not able to display in the view page even alert is also not displaying in the JSON.

Sometimes I am getting  below error because of JSON is empty

```
 [Show/hide message details.] SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

I think there is some issue with JSON.

**Ajax**

```
 $("form[name='search_addSalaryrecord']").validate({ 
// errorElement: 'div', 
submitHandler: function(form) { 
//alert(baseUrl); 
var employee_name = $('#employee_name').val(); 
var crm_id = $('#crm_id').val(); 
var employee_id = $('#employee_id').val(); 
$.ajax({ 
url: baseUrl + "/Employee_control/search_addSalaryrecord", 
method: "POST", 
dataType: "json", 
data: {employee_name: employee_name,crm_id:crm_id,employee_id:employee_id}, 
success: function(response) { 

//$('.search_record tbody').html(response); 
// var data = JSON.parse(response); 

//alert(data.status); 
if (response.status === 'error') 
{ 
alert(response.msg); 

} 

if (response.status === 'success') { 
//alert('data avaliable'); 
alert(response.records); 
console.log(response.records); 

} 
} 
//error: function(error) { console.log(error); } 

}); 
} 
});
```

**Controller**

```
public function search_addSalaryrecord() 
{ 
$employee_name=trim($this->input->post('employee_name')); 
$emp_crmid=trim($this->input->post('crm_id')); 
$employee_id=trim($this->input->post('employee_id')); 

if((!empty($employee_name)) ||(!empty($emp_crmid)) || (!empty($employee_id))){ 
$arr_result =$this->Employee_model->get_salary_search_emp_id($employee_name,$emp_crmid,$employee_id); 
if (!empty($arr_result)){ 
foreach ($arr_result as $row) 
{ 
$result[] = array(  
"name" => $row->firstname.' '.$row->lastname, 
"mobileno" => $row->mobileno, 
"email_id" => $row->email_id, 
"employee_id" => $row->employee_id, 
"month_year" => $row->month.' '.$row->year
); 
} 
//print_r($result); 
$respnonse['status'] = 'success'; 
$respnonse['records'] = $result; 
} 
else 
{ 
$respnonse['status'] = "error"; 
$respnonse['records'] = "No record found"; 
} 
} 
echo json_encode($arr_result); 
exit; 
}
```

Comment: Add an error handler to your ajax and see if the ajax is failing `error: function(error) { console.log(error)); } `

Comment: What is the returned value of `response`? Is it a string? Is it a JSON object that's already been parsed?

Comment: @showdev, I am getting the output in the network tab Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (

            [firstname] => Nilesh
            [lastname] => Verma [mobileno] => [email_id] =>   
        )

) but when checking alert response then alert not displaying

Comment: If my json is empty then also I am getting Array ( ) [{"status":"error","msg":"No record found"}] in the network tab but not displaying the alert

Comment: @MattL. I am getting error in console  SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data[Learn More]

Comment: the controller sending data to the ajax but on able to display there

Comment: The `stdClass Object` does not appear to be JSON encoded, nor does it seem to match your controller code.

Comment: @showdev Yes, I updated the that,Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Nilesh verma   [mobileno] =>1234571010  [email_id] =>mnb@gmail.com ) )

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will help you :**

Use `dataType: "json"` in your ajax to avoid further parsing of response and return `json_encode` data with `exit` from your controller

*Your `ajax` should be like this :*

```
$("form[name='search_record']").validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) 
  {
    var employee_id = $('#employee_id').val();                             
    $.ajax({
      url: baseUrl + "/Employee_control/search_addSalaryrecord",
      method: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {employee_id:employee_id},
      success: function(response) {
        //alert(data.status);   
        if (response.status == 'error')
        {
          alert(response.msg);
          $('.personel_info').empty();
        } 
        if (response.status == 'success') 
        {
          alert(response.records);
          $('.personel_info').empty();
          $('.personel_info').show();
          var trHTML = '';
          $.each(data.records, function (i, o){
            $('#name_emp').text(o.name);
              $('#mobileno_emp').text(o.mobileno);
              $('#employee_email').text(o.employee_email);
          });
        }
      }          
    });
  }
});
```

Your controller's method `search_addSalaryrecord` should be like this :

```
public function search_addSalaryrecord()
{
  $employee_id  = trim($this->input->post('employee_id'));
  if(!empty($employee_id))
  {
    $arr_result = $this->Employee_model->get_salary_search_emp_id($employee_id);
    if (! empty($arr_result))
    {
        foreach ($arr_result as $row)
        {
          $result[] = array(
              "name" => $row->firstname.' '.$row->lastname,
              "mobileno" => $row->mobileno,
              "email_id" => $row->email_id,
            );
        }
        $respnonse['status'] = 'success';
        $respnonse['records'] = $result;
    } 
    else
    {
        $respnonse['status'] = "error";
        $respnonse['records'] = "No record found";
    }
  }
  echo json_encode($respnonse);
  exit;
}
```

Comment: A little explanation might be helpful. What was wrong and what did you do to resolve it?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, Should I use response.status  instated of data.status?

Comment: in the success response, I tried success: function(data) {
            alert(data); and I am getting the "[object Object]" in the alert.

Comment: try with `data.records` ,ur response structure should be same for both if and else case

Comment: Hello @pradeep, I comment out all the code in the success  and just added  if (data.status == 'success') {alert(data.records); 
      console.log(data.records);} but trust me it's not displaying any data.

Comment: One more think I want to know about how data.status will get the success output from the controller because we are using response in the sucess funciton.

Comment: changed controller code pls check and make sure your `$result` has some data

Comment: @pradeep, I am getting the data in the result I added   print_r($result); inside foreach and I am getting the output in the network tab

Comment: I updated both ajax code and controller code pls check it and let me know what u got?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176209/discussion-between-user9437856-and-pradeep).

Comment: @pradeep, I shared my code in the chat. Please check it.

Comment: @pradeep, I just want to know. why you used "data.records"  because we haven't declared the data? $.each(data.records, function (i, o){

Comment: I almost close. I am getting the output in console           console.log(response.records); but for each not working. I tried          $.each(response.records, function (i, o){ but still not displaying it.